# Why Xpath 3.0 works, but Xquery 3.0 doesn't work with the same expression

Tags: xpath, xquery

I launched Xpath in Oxygen. In Xpath 3.0 found what i need but in Xquery 3.0 doesn't find.

This is my Xpath expression

```
//table[tbody/tr/th/p[contains(text(), 'All Water System Contacts')]]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]
```

This is my xml code
I put part code.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" summary="." width="640">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                <p>All Water System Contacts </p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Communication</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">AC - Administrative Contact - GENERAL MANAGER </td>
            <td align="center">GRANT, JOHN, W <br/> PO BOX 869<br/> BIG SPRING, TX&nbsp;79721-0869 </td>
            <td align="center">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse"
                    width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th><b>Electronic Type</b></th>
                            <th><b>Value</b></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse"
                    width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th><b>Phone Type</b></th>
                            <th><b>Value</b></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">BUS - Business</td>
                            <td align="center">432-267-6341 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">FAX - Facsimile</td>
                            <td align="center">432-267-3121 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">BUS - Business</td>
                            <td align="center">432-267-6070 </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">OW - Owner </td>
            <td align="center">COLORADO RIVER MUNICIPAL WATER DISTRICT <br/> PO BOX 869<br/> BIG
                SPRING, TX&nbsp;79721-0869 </td>
            <td align="center"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried different functions.

I don't know why it doesn't work and what difference

Please help me.

Comment: Please explain in detail which version of oXygen you use and how exactly you use XQuery with it and that input snippet because when I try it oXygen directly complains about an `entity "nbsp"` being "referenced, but not declared". So I don't see how oXygen could first parse the input to be able to use XPath or XQuery.

Comment: BTW, it's generally helpful to find the *shortest possible document* that reproduces the problem (and the shortest possible query!). If you just made your document `<table><tbody/></table>` and the query `//table`, for example, that itself would still be sufficient to repro, and would make for a much shorter and simpler question.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your real, complete input has an XHTML default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` and in oXygen for XPath you have the setting enabled to "use the default namespace of the root element" so your path works with XPath out of the box while for XQuery you need to make sure you explicitly set

```
declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
```

in the prolog of your XQuery file or code sample.